# why some images showing blank/black in imageView

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

Why do some images show blank/black? These images are fetched from the server by Picasso library.

This is the screen shot

[image: this is the screen shot]

**this is code**

```
  Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(profileModel.getDoc_pic()).into(docPic);
```

Comment: Debug your project and get these image URLs. Paste the URL in the browser and see if it is loaded successfully in browser or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About **[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**

> **Place Holders**
>
> Picasso supports both download and error placeholders as optional
>   features.

you can use place holder and error for this purpose.

**Try :**

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(profileModel.getDoc_pic()).placeholder(R.drawable.tmp_image).error(R.drawable.tmp_image).into(docPic);
```

**In manifest need to add Internet permission :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: actually this is not the solution..these images shwoing in my emulator 7.1 version but not showing some images in my mobile lolipop version

Comment: @MohammadIrfan yes because it depends on internet speed and server response time.. some times it takes much time so better to put place holder and error images so you can get your error and user also understand that images are being loading

Comment: @MohammadIrfan also test with some more devices.. real devices.. because this is not due to mobile versions (7.1/5)

Comment: Have you included Internet permission in your Manifest file?

Comment: Try my solution once just copy paste and replace different placeholder and error images

Comment: Yes @MohammadIrfan you need a Internet permission also.. you have added it?

Comment: yes ofcourse i added internet permission thats why some images showing properly na

Comment: but @VishvaDave i did your solution but app crashed and i think this is not internet  speed problem ...

Comment: what is error log? have you replaced images with yours?